# Ruby on rails microservices using HTTP explanation needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, microservices

So, i currently have a pretty big monolithic rails app. I want to split the app up into separate micro-service APIs, with a main app as the gateway. I've been reading a lot about how to do this and think i understand, however there isn't much info on how the communication between the main app and the micro-services. I understand that i can do this in a variety of ways but i want to use HTTP.

Can someone provide an example of how this setup might look and how the communication works (in code) between the main app and the micro-service?

Thanks

Comment: This question is bit too broad to answer easily. You might want to give a specific example.

Comment: I agree with @MikeGorski that this question is too broad. Asking for a code sample seems to be premature unless you really don't know what you meant when you said "I want to use HTTP". Based on the statement, the services would just communicate by making an HTTP request and getting an HTTP response. The solution would then be to use Google how to make an HTTP request if you don't already know how to. People might overlook this question because its asking for something too simple and vague.

Answer (score -1):

For APIs in Rails, see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html. I suggest to use a RESTful API, because REST uses the normal HTTP verbs and fits well to the Rails philosophy, see e.g. https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application